# Magento 2 - Getting Order By ID hangs

Tags: magento2, orders, sales-order, repositories

I have the following class

```
<?php
namespace Company\Module\Plugin;


class myClass
{
    protected $_orderRepository;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
    ) {
        $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    }

    public function processOrder($orderId)
    {

        $order = $this->_orderRepository->get($orderId);

        var_dump($order->getItems());

        exit;
    }
}
```

However when it gets to running "$order = $this->_orderRepository->get($orderId);" then my system runs out of memory. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: try $order->getItems() in foreach....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

var_dump is not an good idea to check Object.

**That why you are getting hangup.You need to use X-debug for this**